# jQuery: need help hiding previously viewed element(s)

Tags: jquery, hide, show-hide, show

Please, be kind, I am just learning how to code...

I have built out a simple photo album page using 'hide' and 'show' to navigate between the different albums. However, I am running into an issue with not being able to 'clear' the previously viewed photos from the previous album.

Here's a short video showing my issue: http://screencast.com/t/RrA0bygQm

In my index.html and main.js pages I have the following code for hiding and showing the relevant albums:

```
$(".albums-nav a").on("click", function(e) {
    var target = $(this);
    var targetName = target.attr("href");

    $(targetName).addClass("active");
    $(targetName).show();


    $('.album-containers').hide();
    $('.albums-nav').show();

});

<!-- adding the side menu nav -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 sidemenu">
            <div class="list-group albums-nav" id="albums-nav">
                <a href="#album1-photos" class="list-group-item">Album 1</a>
                <a href="#album2-photos" class="list-group-item">Album 2</a>
                <a href="#album3-photos" class="list-group-item">Album 3</a>
                <a href="#album4-photos" class="list-group-item">Album 4</a>
                <a href="#album5-photos" class="list-group-item">Album 5</a>
                <a href="#album6-photos" class="list-group-item">Album 6</a>
            </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-9 albums">
            <section id="album1-photos" class="album1-photos">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <img src="img/album1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                        <h3>Photo 1</h3>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <img src="img/album2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                        <h3>Photo 2</h3>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <img src="img/album1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                        <h3>Photo 3</h3>
                    </div>          
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <img src="img/album2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                        <h3>Photo 4</h3>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <img src="img/album1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                        <h3>Photo 5</h3>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <img src="img/album2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                        <h3>Photo 6</h3>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </section>
```

My thoughts were to add a new class ("active") to the target and hide all other elements without it, but I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to do this.

Suggestions?

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: @guest271314 sorry about that. Added it for the relevant section.

Comment: Codecademy.com is a great place to learn jQuery. Give it a try

Comment: @Mustaghees i might actually check that out sometime, haha. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

css

```
/* set `.albums [id^=album]` to `display:none` */
.albums [id^=album] {
  display:none;
}
```

js

```
$(".albums-nav a").on("click", function(e) {
  // hide all `.album`
  $(".albums [id^=album]").hide();
  // show `target` `.album`
  $($(this).attr("href")).show();
});
```

```js
$(".albums-nav a").on("click", function(e) {
  $(".albums [id^=album]").hide();
  $($(this).attr("href")).show();

});
```

```css
.albums [id^=album] {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 sidemenu">
            <div class="list-group albums-nav" id="albums-nav">
                <a href="#album1-photos" class="list-group-item">Album 1</a>
                <a href="#album2-photos" class="list-group-item">Album 2</a>
                <a href="#album3-photos" class="list-group-item">Album 3</a>
                <a href="#album4-photos" class="list-group-item">Album 4</a>
                <a href="#album5-photos" class="list-group-item">Album 5</a>
                <a href="#album6-photos" class="list-group-item">Album 6</a>
            </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-9 albums">
            <section id="album1-photos" class="album1-photos">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <img src="img/album1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                        <h3>Photo 1</h3>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <img src="img/album2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                        <h3>Photo 2</h3>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <img src="img/album1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                        <h3>Photo 3</h3>
                    </div>          
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <img src="img/album2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                        <h3>Photo 4</h3>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <img src="img/album1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                        <h3>Photo 5</h3>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <img src="img/album2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                        <h3>Photo 6</h3>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </section>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: That works. I have never used the XOR operators before. Thanks